# Correções de texto na página sobre

Tags: bug, status-pronto, localização, formatação

Na página [sobre](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/about) do SOPT está assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Na mina opinião o texto de votar contra está confuso:

> Votar contra (custa **1** pontos de reputação nas respostas)

Poderia ser:

> Votar contra (em respostas custa **1** ponto de reputação)

Em outra parte da página, falta um espaço na frase para deixar o texto em negrito:

> **ferramentas de moderação**especiais

Comment: Descobri que como moderador tenho direito de editar algumas partes dessa página. Infelizmente o trecho que você citou não está entre elas. Vou encaminhar o problema para quem possa resolver.

Comment: @bfavaretto bom saber, eu fiz algumas perguntas de tradução que ainda não foram atendidas, se puder dar uma olhada. Existe muito mais coisas (pequenas mas tem) que tem que traduzir entretanto eu nem tava mais criando perguntas por que acho que o processo estava meio lento, mas agora se embalar eu volto a colaborar com essa parte da tradução. Como eu sou meio chato eu sou bom para ficar achando erros :p

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consertado. Por partes:

- **Erro de markdown**
  Foi acertado. Vai pro ar no próximo build
- **Concordância**
  O texto original, em inglês, é automático e diz:
  `Vote down (costs **$rep$** rep on answers)`
  De forma a manter a concordância, mesmo que um dia o custo passe a ser maior que 1 ponto, mudei para:
  `Votar contra (em respostas custa **$rep$** de reputação)`

Não sei se está claro o suficiente, mas vai pro ar no próximo build. Sugestões são bem vindas.